# How to show invisible line endings in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I would like to display invisible line endings in Sublime Text 3, as for example in Notepad++. How can we do that?

This is useful because when the automatic word wrap mode is ON for example, because it becomes hard to distinguish soft line breaks from real ones.

Answer (score 47):

The package [RawLineEdit](http://facelessuser.github.io/RawLineEdit/usage/) is pretty good for this. It toggles on-and-off a mode where you view and can edit line endings by selecting `Raw Line Edit: Toggle` from the Sublime <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> command prompt.

This is good if you want to be able to flick line endings visibility on and off on the occasions when you want to see it (it's not the best option if you want line endings to be *always* visible).

It's also very useful for seeing (and editing) if you've ended up with `crlf` problems, with windows-style `cr` carriage return characters getting mixed up with the standard `lf` line end characters shown as `¬`:

[image]

Comment: I'm using this package to edit tab delimiters based CSV files and it works like a charm. It makes data files more readable.

Comment: This plugin killed my syntax highlighting

Comment: Yeah you turn it on when you need line endings, then turn it off when you're done with them and you want normal syntax highlighting back - "it's not the best option if you want line endings to be always visible"

Comment: It shows icons instead of "CR", "LF". Where is to find the meaning of these icons?

Comment: does it exist in Sublime 4?

Answer (score 6):

I have written a basic plugin to display line endings as an explicit character, inline. There's certainly some room for improvement but it does the job.

It is available here: https://github.com/sdive/sublime-text_managelineendings

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions found here didn't work for the character I was encountering (U+2028). I found that this plugin was able to show me where the character was occurring:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Highlight%20Dodgy%20Chars

Answer (score -7):

`ctrl + shift + p` on editor
now, type `toggle word wrap` and select it